# CardLayout.show() not working

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm attempting to use CardLayout to make the main panel(that is, the panel that everything else is on) display a different panel(the default one being where the user can browse the products) so that the user could view their cart and checkout. I believe that I should have the ButtonListener and everything set up, however the CardLayout.show method is still not doing its thing. Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you for any help.

- mainPanel - the main panel. Everything is ultimately attached to it
- cartPanel - the panel that the checkout button should make visible
- orderingPanel - the panel where the user can browse the products. infoPanel and     -invntryPanel are attached to it
- infoPanel - the panel that changes based off of the selection in the JList candyList
- invntryPanel - the panel that holds candyList

Source:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class ClientApp extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientApp();
    }

    private JButton switchCard;
    private JPanel infoPanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel cartPanel;
    private JPanel orderingPanel;
    private JList candyList;
    private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel checkoutPanel;
    private JButton checkoutButton;
    private JTextField acidPopsTF;
    private JTextField bertieBottsTF;
    private JTextField bloodPopsTF;
    private JTextField cauldronCakesTF;
    private JTextField charmChocTF;
    private JTextField chocoballsTF;
    private JTextField chocCauldronsTF;
    private JTextField chocFrogsTF;
    private JTextField chocWandsTF;
    private JTextField roachClustersTF;
    private JTextField crystalPineappleTF;
    private JTextField droobleGumTF;
    private JTextField explodeBonbonsTF;
    private JTextField fizzWhizTF;
    private JTextField iceMiceTF;
    private JTextField jellySlugsTF;
    private JTextField liquorWandsTF;
    private JTextField pepImpsTF;
    private JTextField pinkCocoIceTF;
    private JTextField spindleSpidersTF;
    private JTextField sugarQuillsTF;
    private JTextField wizochocTF;
    private JTextField shockChocTF;
    private ArrayList cart;
    private Object[] cartArray;

    public ClientApp()
    {
        this.setSize(750,400);
        this.setTitle("Honeydukes Muggle Ordering System");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();

        mainPanel = new JPanel(cl);
        cartPanel = new JPanel();
        orderingPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        infoPanel = new JPanel(cl);
        JPanel invntryPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        checkoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


        //Creating the array for the invntryPanel Jlist

        String[] candy = {"Acid Pops", "Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans",
                          "Blood-flavoured Lollipops",
                          "Cauldron Cakes", "Charm Choc",
                          "Chocoballs", "Chocolate Cauldrons",
                          "Chocolate Frogs","Chocolate Wands",
                          "Cockroach Clusters", "Crystallised Pineapple",
                          "Drooble's Best Blowing Gum", "Exploding Bonbons",
                          "Fizzing Whizbees", "Ice Mice",
                          "Jelly Slugs", "Liquourice Wands",
                          "Pepper Imps", "Pink Coconut Ice",
                          "Shock-o-Choc", "Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders",
                          "Sugar Quills", "Wizochoc"};
        candyList = new JList(candy);
        candyList.setVisibleRowCount(18);
        candyList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


        //Creating a scrollpane for the JList
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(candyList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                             JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        invntryPanel.add(scroll);

        switchCard = new JButton("View Product");
        switchCard.addActionListener(bl);
        invntryPanel.add(switchCard, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //Creating the cards
        JPanel startCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel acidPopsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel bertieBottsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel bloodPopsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel cauldronCakesCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel charmChocCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel chocoballsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel chocCauldronsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel chocFrogsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel chocWandsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel roachClustersCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel crystalPineappleCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel droobleGumCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel explodeBonbonsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel fizzWhizCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel iceMiceCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel jellySlugsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel liquorWandsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pepImpsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pinkCocoIceCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel shockChocCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel spindleSpidersCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel sugarQuillsCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel wizochocCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        //Adding the cards to the infoPanel
        infoPanel.add(startCard, "Start");
        infoPanel.add(acidPopsCard, "Acid Pops");
        infoPanel.add(bertieBottsCard, "Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans");
        infoPanel.add(bloodPopsCard, "Blood-flavoured Lollipops");
        infoPanel.add(cauldronCakesCard, "Cauldron Cakes");
        infoPanel.add(charmChocCard, "Charm Choc");
        infoPanel.add(chocoballsCard, "Chocoballs");
        infoPanel.add(chocCauldronsCard, "Chocolate Cauldrons");
        infoPanel.add(chocFrogsCard, "Chocolate Frogs");
        infoPanel.add(chocWandsCard, "Chocolate Wands");
        infoPanel.add(roachClustersCard, "Cockroach Clusters");
        infoPanel.add(crystalPineappleCard, "Crystallised Pineapple");
        infoPanel.add(droobleGumCard, "Drooble's Best Blowing Gum");
        infoPanel.add(explodeBonbonsCard, "Exploding Bonbons");
        infoPanel.add(fizzWhizCard, "Fizzing Whizbees");
        infoPanel.add(iceMiceCard, "Ice Mice");
        infoPanel.add(jellySlugsCard, "Jelly Slugs");
        infoPanel.add(liquorWandsCard, "Liquourice Wands");
        infoPanel.add(pepImpsCard, "Pepper Imps");
        infoPanel.add(pinkCocoIceCard, "Pink Coconut Ice");
        infoPanel.add(shockChocCard, "Shock-o-Choc");
        infoPanel.add(spindleSpidersCard, "Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders");
        infoPanel.add(sugarQuillsCard, "Sugar Quills");
        infoPanel.add(wizochocCard, "Wizochoc");

        //building the cards
        startBuilder("honeydukes.jpg", "<html><center>Welcome to the Honeydukes Muggle Ordering System!<br />Please select from one of our products to the left to begin!</center></html>", startCard);
        verticalBuilder("acidPops.jpg", "<html><center>One of our more exotic treats, Acid Pops are sure to pack a punch!<br /><small>Disclaimer: Honeydukes is not responsible for any injury resulting from use of our products.</small><br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", acidPopsTF, acidPopsCard);
        verticalBuilder("BertieBotts.jpg", "<html><center>A classic wizard candy, Bertie Bott's are known for having a danger in every mouthful. Is that light brown one toffee, or is it earwax? Only one way to find out!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$16.95</center></html>", bertieBottsTF, bertieBottsCard);
        verticalBuilder("bloodpop.jpg", "<html><center>For those of more unusual tastes, we have this most interesting lollipop. We won't ask any questions, and anonymity is guaranteed.<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", bloodPopsTF, bloodPopsCard);
        verticalBuilder("cauldroncake.jpg", "<html><center>A wizarding favourite, cauldron cakes are chocolate on the outside, and pure heaven on the inside. No desert is complete without one!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$14.95</center></html>", cauldronCakesTF, cauldronCakesCard);
        verticalBuilder("charmchoc.jpg", "<html><center>A candy staple, not only is Charm Choc made of the finest chocolate, it's also charmed for extra flavour!<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", charmChocTF, charmChocCard);
        horizontalBuilder("chocoballs.jpg", "<html><center>One of our most popular candies, Chocoballs are chocolate on the outside, but the inside is full of delicious strawberry mousse and clotted cream!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", chocoballsTF, chocoballsCard);
        verticalBuilder("choccauldrons.jpg", "<html><center>A wizarding favourite, each and every Chocolate Cauldron are filled to the brim with our own special brew of Firewhiskey!<br /><br />NOTICE: The Ministry of Magic would like to remind all that Firewhisky is an alcoholic beverage, and is not to be consumed by those who are underaged.<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$14.95</center></html>", chocCauldronsTF, chocCauldronsCard);
        verticalBuilder("chocfrogs.jpg", "<html><center>One of the most famous wizarding sweets, Chocolate Frogs are made of the finest Croakoa, enabling them to behave like actual frogs! Each Chocolate Frog comes with card featuring a famous witch or wizard! Try to collect them all!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$14.95</center></html>", chocFrogsTF, chocFrogsCard);
        horizontalBuilder("chocwands.jpg", "<html><center>Popular as both a gag gift and a tasty treat, chocolate wands are one candy that nobody leaves the shop without!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", chocWandsTF, chocWandsCard);
        verticalBuilder("cockroachclusters.jpg", "<html><center>Great for tricking friends or quenching your insatiable hunger for cockroaches, these peculiar treats will never get old!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", roachClustersTF, roachClustersCard);
        verticalBuilder("crystalpineapple.jpg", "<html><center>Endorsed by Professor Horace Slughorn himself, Crystallised pineapple consists of the best pineapples diced up, and then cooked in sugar syrup. This is one sweet treat you don't want to be without!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", crystalPineappleTF, crystalPineappleCard);
        verticalBuilder("gum.jpg", "<html><center>Guaranteed to never lose its flavour, Drooble's Best Blowing Gum will let you blow bubbles that last for days, and is the best wizarding gum out there!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$2.95</center></html>", droobleGumTF, droobleGumCard);
        verticalBuilder("bonbons.jpg", "<html><center>Produced by Kaboon Choco Ltd., these treats pop in your mouth -- literally!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", explodeBonbonsTF, explodeBonbonsCard);
        verticalBuilder("whizbees.jpg", "<html><center>Made from delicious sherbert, Fizzing Whizbees have the effect of also causing you to float a few inches off the ground while sucking on them!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", fizzWhizTF, fizzWhizCard);
        verticalBuilder("mice.jpg", "<html><center>Charmed to stay cold up to the point of being enjoyed, ice mice will also cause your teeeth to chatter and squeak!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", iceMiceTF, iceMiceCard);
        verticalBuilder("slugs.jpg", "Perhaps the single most popular sweet, Jelly Slugs are a classic!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$2.95</center></html>", jellySlugsTF, jellySlugsCard);
        verticalBuilder("liqwand.jpg", "<html><center>Another favourite, these wands won't win you any duels, but they sure are tasty!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$9.95</center></html>", liquorWandsTF, liquorWandsCard);
        verticalBuilder("imps.jpg", "<html><center>Famous for making anyone who eats them smoke at the ears and nose, these spicy treats are delicious!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$4.95</center></html>", pepImpsTF, pepImpsCard);
        verticalBuilder("pinkice.jpg", "<html><center>Amazing in every way, these shimmering pink squares are even more enjoyable than they look!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$4.95</center></html>", pinkCocoIceTF, pinkCocoIceCard);
        verticalBuilder("shock.jpg", "<html><center>Add some SHOCK to your Choc-o-late! Perfect for practical jokes, and tasty too!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$4.95</center></html>", shockChocTF, shockChocCard);
        verticalBuilder("spiders.jpg", "<html><center>Made entirely out of liquorice, these treats are even bewitched to seem alive!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$4.95</center></html>", spindleSpidersTF, spindleSpidersCard);
        verticalBuilder("quill.jpg", "<html><center>Perfect for nibbling on during lectures, the professor will never know the difference between you thinking and you enjoying a delicious sugar quill!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$1.95</center></html>", sugarQuillsTF, sugarQuillsCard);
        verticalBuilder("wizochoc.jpg", "<html><center>There's been an age old debate between wizards of all ages as to whether CharmChoc or WizoChoc is better. Now Muggles can join in as well!<br /><br /><br />Type the quantity of this product you would like to order below.<br /><br />$5.95</center></html>", wizochocTF, wizochocCard);

        checkoutButton = new JButton("Checkout");
        checkoutButton.addActionListener(bl);
        checkoutPanel.add(checkoutButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        orderingPanel.add(checkoutPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        orderingPanel.add(invntryPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        orderingPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(orderingPanel, "Ordering");
        mainPanel.add(cartPanel, "Cart");
        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    void startBuilder(String p, String l, JPanel n)
    {
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(p));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        n.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(l);
    n.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    void verticalBuilder(String p, String l, JTextField t, JPanel n)
    {
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(p));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        n.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(l);
    n.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    t = new JTextField();
    n.add(t, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    void horizontalBuilder(String p, String l, JTextField t, JPanel n)
    {
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(p));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        n.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    JLabel Lbl = new JLabel(l);
    n.add(Lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    t = new JTextField();
    n.add(t, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == switchCard)
            {
                cl.show(infoPanel, (String)candyList.getSelectedValue());
            }

            if (e.getSource() == checkoutButton)
            {
                NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

                String acidPopsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, acidPopsTF));
                String bertieBottsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 16.95, bertieBottsTF));
                String bloodPopsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, bloodPopsTF));
                String cauldronCakesCost = cf.format(Total(1, 14.95, cauldronCakesTF));
                String charmChocCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, charmChocTF));
                String chocoballsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, chocoballsTF));
                String chocCauldronsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 14.95, chocCauldronsTF));
                String chocFrogsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 14.95, chocFrogsTF));
                String chocWandsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, chocWandsTF));
                String roachClustersCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, roachClustersTF));
                String crystalPineappleCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, crystalPineappleTF));
                String droobleGumCost = cf.format(Total(1, 2.95, droobleGumTF));
                String explodeBonbonsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, explodeBonbonsTF));
                String fizzWhizCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, fizzWhizTF));
                String iceMiceCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, iceMiceTF));
                String jellySlugsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 2.95, jellySlugsTF));
                String liquorWandsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 9.95, liquorWandsTF));
                String pepImpsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 4.95, pepImpsTF));
                String pinkCocoIceCost = cf.format(Total(1, 4.95, pinkCocoIceTF));
                String shockChocCost = cf.format(Total(1, 4.95, shockChocTF));
                String spindleSpidersCost = cf.format(Total(1, 4.95, spindleSpidersTF));
                String sugarQuillsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 1.95, sugarQuillsTF));
                String wizochocCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, wizochocTF));

                int acidPopsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, acidPopsTF);
                int bertieBottsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, bertieBottsTF);
                int bloodPopsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, bloodPopsTF);
                int cauldronCakesNum = (int)Total(0, 0, cauldronCakesTF);
                int charmChocNum = (int)Total(0, 0, charmChocTF);
                int chocoballsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, chocoballsTF);
                int chocCauldronsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, chocCauldronsTF);
                int chocFrogsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, chocFrogsTF);
                int chocWandsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, chocWandsTF);
                int roachClustersNum = (int)Total(0, 0, roachClustersTF);
                int crystalPineappleNum = (int)Total(0, 0, crystalPineappleTF);
                int droobleGumNum = (int)Total(0, 0, droobleGumTF);
                int explodeBonbonsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, explodeBonbonsTF);
                int fizzWhizNum = (int)Total(0, 0, fizzWhizTF);
                int iceMiceNum = (int)Total(0, 0, iceMiceTF);
                int jellySlugsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, jellySlugsTF);
                int liquorWandsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, liquorWandsTF);
                int pepImpsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, pepImpsTF);
                int pinkCocoIceNum = (int)Total(0, 0, pinkCocoIceTF);
                int shockChocNum = (int)Total(0, 0, shockChocTF);
                int spindleSpidersNum = (int)Total(0, 0, spindleSpidersTF);
                int sugarQuillsNum = (int)Total(0, 0, sugarQuillsTF);
                int wizochocNum = (int)Total(0, 0, wizochocTF);

                cart = new ArrayList();

                addCart("Acid Pops", acidPopsNum, acidPopsCost);
                addCart("Bertie Botts Every Flavour Beans", bertieBottsNum, bertieBottsCost);
                addCart("Blood-flavoured Lollipops", bloodPopsNum, bloodPopsCost);
                addCart("Cauldron Cakes", cauldronCakesNum, cauldronCakesCost);
                addCart("Charm Choc", charmChocNum, charmChocCost);
                addCart("Chocoballs", chocoballsNum, chocoballsCost);
                addCart("Chocolate Cauldrons", chocCauldronsNum, chocCauldronsCost);
                addCart("Chocolate Frogs", chocFrogsNum, chocFrogsCost);
                addCart("Chocolate Wands", chocWandsNum, chocWandsCost);
                addCart("Cockroach Clusters", roachClustersNum, roachClustersCost);
                addCart("Crystallised Pineapple", crystalPineappleNum, cauldronCakesCost);
                addCart("Drooble's Best Blowing Gum", droobleGumNum, droobleGumCost);
                addCart("Exploding Bonbons", explodeBonbonsNum, explodeBonbonsCost);
                addCart("Fizzing Whizbees", fizzWhizNum, fizzWhizCost);
                addCart("Ice Mice", iceMiceNum, iceMiceCost);
                addCart("Jelly Slugs", jellySlugsNum, jellySlugsCost);
                addCart("Liquorice Wands", liquorWandsNum, liquorWandsCost);
                addCart("Pepper Imps", pepImpsNum, pepImpsCost);
                addCart("Pink Coconut Ice", pinkCocoIceNum, pinkCocoIceCost);
                addCart("Shock-o-Choc", shockChocNum, shockChocCost);
                addCart("Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders", spindleSpidersNum, spindleSpidersCost);
                addCart("Sugar Quills", sugarQuillsNum, sugarQuillsCost);
                addCart("Wizochoc", wizochocNum, wizochocCost);

                cart.remove(cart.size());
                cartArray = cart.toArray();

                cl.show(mainPanel, "Cart");
            }
        }

        double Total(int i, double p, JTextField t)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    return (p* (Integer.parseInt(t.getText())));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) { return 0; }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return Integer.parseInt(t.getText());
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) { return 0; }
            }
        }

        void addCart(String p, int n, String c)
        {
            if (n > 0)
            {
                cart.add(p);
                cart.add(n);
                cart.add(c);
                cart.add("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you can only add the CardLayout to one component. You seem to be adding it to two. More importantly,  you need to test these new constructs in a small test program, not a large program with multiple other unrelated issues.

Comment: I've tried creating another instance of the CardLayout and setting it up in case that was the issue. Same result.

Comment: then test it in a small program and show us what happens. Your code above has much too much code unrelated to your problem at hand, I think.

Comment: I've done some fiddling, and I believe that, for whatever reason, the problem lies with the ButtonListener. It's not doing anything when the Checkout button is pressed, however it does follow the instructions under it for the View Product button. Ideas?

Comment: Running your code and clicking Checkout, I get a nullpointer on line 329 `return (p* (Integer.parseInt(t.getText())));`. And for your own sanity, you might want to take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html .

Answer (score 0):

Dude, there are many corrections in your code to be implemented. Here is the list -

In the methods verticalBuilder/horizontalBuilder you are passing objects to be added to the corresponding panels..but these methods are actually creating new objects (t) for the JTextField..see line#228. So when the method 'Total' is called for the first time from the line#242 i.e String acidPopsCost = cf.format(Total(1, 5.95, acidPopsTF)); you are actually refering to the original JTextField object 'acidPopsTF' which is null and is not initialized and that is why line#329 throws a nullpointer exception.

So instead of using a methods verticalBuilder/horizontalBuilder,  initialize the objects first, add it to the panel.
e.g-

```
picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(IMAGE_URL)),SwingConstants.CENTER);
acidPopsCard.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

acidPopsCard.add(new JLabel(YOUR_HTML_STRING), BorderLayout.CENTER);

acidPopsTF = new JTextField();
acidPopsCard.add(acidPopsTF,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Look @ line#302 you have used cauldronCakesCost instead of crystalPineappleCost that can again change the result.

After making the changes I am sure you can see the expected results.